# Inconsistency in retreiving COUNT(*) from table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my PL/SQL block, there is an INSERT statement which takes data from a view and inserts into table. The next statement is taking count(*) from this table which is just now inserted with new data.

There is NO commit happening in between. Once the count from this table is zero, an exception will be raised and program stops there.

I am not encountering 0 count in a non-prod instance but in Production instance, the count came back as zero in the past few runs. What could be the issue here ?

Below is the code snippet

```
delete from table1;

   INSERT INTO table1
     (c1,c2,c3,....,c12)
     SELECT a1,
            a2,
            a3,
            min(a4) a4,
            min(a5) a5,
            a6,
            a7,
            a8,
            a9,
            a10,
            SYSDATE
       FROM view1
       group by c1,
      c2,
      c3,
      c4,
      c5,
      c6,
      c7,
      c8,
      c9,
      c10
     

  select COUNT(*) INTO v_no_recs
     from table1;

   if v_no_recs = 0 then
    raise e_zero_rec_exception;
   end if;
```

Comment: One possibility is that the view returns no rows in the production envrionment.

Comment: can you share the pl/sql block of code where you find this behaviour.(a simulated example with basic tables)

Comment: Thanks for you question; can you share your code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - That's not the case, the view has data and the table also has data when I check. However, count(*) from table soon after the insert seems to be failing during the program execution.

Comment: Unless the table didn't get loaded there isn't reason to show 0 records. Have u always got this error in production.? If not what has changed in the view definition of view1. When block executes in production it would use the schema of the prod user where if there is a synonym for view1 or another local table called view1, it would use that ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your view has no data there is no way no records are not inserted. You do not have a `WHERE` clause and such `min()` will always give you something back.

Here is simplified what you you are inserting:

```
WITH no_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS lothold_cd, 'id-1' AS aps_site_id
    FROM dual
   WHERE 1 = 2
),
records_to_insert AS (
SELECT min(lothold_cd)
  FROM no_data
 GROUP BY aps_site_id
)
SELECT count(*) FROM records_to_insert;

count(*)
--------
0
```

In the above if you comment out the `GROUP BY` you will get 1 row back. It is the GROUP BY of an empty table/view which will cause no records to be selected despte the fact you are using an aggregate function in your `SELECT`

Check your `WHERE` conditions inside the view definition (if any) it has to be something you do not expect.

Also rather than running the `INSERT` then running the counting it is a better approach to check SQL%ROWCOUNT.

```
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    raise e_inv_size_exception;
END IF;
```